# Pandoc numbered example list doesn't work with custom writer

Tags: lua, pandoc

Pandoc has amazing extension `example_lists` for continuously numbered list throughout the document. We try to use custom writer to produce html, but numbering is broken in result html. Consider the following md-code:

```
(@) item 1
(@) item 2

## header ##

(@) item 3
```

Pandoc produces the following html-page by default:

```
1. item 1
2. item 2
  header
3. item 3
```

But with custom writer (we took example with `pandoc --print-default-data-file sample.lua`) it produces:

```
1. item 1
2. item 2
  header
1. item 3
```

Sample lua-writer contains the following code for ordered list processing:

```
function OrderedList(items)
  local buffer = {}
  for _, item in pairs(items) do
    table.insert(buffer, "<li>" .. item .. "</li>")
  end
  return "<ol>\n" .. table.concat(buffer, "\n") .. "\n</ol>"
end
```

If add `print` for first elements of pairs from `items` table

```
function OrderedList(items)
  local buffer = {}
  for elem, item in pairs(items) do
    print(elem)
    table.insert(buffer, "<li>" .. item .. "</li>")
  end
  return "<ol>\n" .. table.concat(buffer, "\n") .. "\n</ol>"
end
```

we'll see just final list items' numbers:

```
1
2
1
```

So I don't think the problem is in the writer itself. Have you any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through [pandoc sources](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) for custom writer ([src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Custom.hs](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Custom.hs)) you may find that `OrderedList` function actually gets four arguments, third of which is list style. You should be interested in `Example` list style. So you could update `OrderedList` implementation accordingly: introduce global variable for counting total items in `Example`-list, alter function code basing on list style (add start attribute in `ol` html tag for `Example`-list).

```
-- for counting examples (@)
local ExampleIdx = 1

function OrderedList(items, num, sty, delim)
  local buffer = {}
  for _, item in pairs(items) do
    table.insert(buffer, "<li>" .. item .. "</li>")
  end
  local start = ""
  if sty == "Example" then
    if ExampleIdx > 1 then
      start = ' start="' .. ExampleIdx .. '" '
    end
    ExampleIdx = ExampleIdx + table.getn(items)
  end
  return '<ol' .. start .. '>\n' .. table.concat(buffer, "\n") .. "\n</ol>"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to keep an `ExampleIdx` global variable as in Artem Pelenitsyn's answer.  All you have to do is make your list item writer sensitive to the second parameter (the start number:  `num` in Pelenitsyn's code).  Note that you can use `pandoc -t native` to inspect the AST that is being passed to the writer; you'll see that the start number is set appropriately by the reader.

```
function OrderedList(items, num)
  local buffer = {}
  for _, item in pairs(items) do
     table.insert(buffer, "<li>" .. item .. "</li>")
  end
  local start = ""
  if num > 1 then
    start = ' start="' .. num .. '" '
  end
  return '<ol' .. start .. '>\n' .. table.concat(buffer, "\n") .. "\n</ol>"
end
```